# Updating OpenStreetMap maps database of own tile server?

Tags: openstreetmap, maps, osm2pgsql

I am working with a osm2pgsql database, and I do not know wheter I can use Osmupdate or not because in the StreetMapWiki it says furry-sansa should be used for osm2pgsql databases. The problem is furry-sansa does not only make the updating but also gives a styling to the maps, something I want to avoid.

Does Osmupdate work with osm2pgsql?

Should I modify furry-sansa in order to obtain only the updating function?*

*Modifying furry-sansa would be hard for me.

Comment: See the paragraph *Updating* at https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/building-a-tile-server-from-packages/ for instructions on how to keep your tile server up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the scai's comment above, see also [these instructions](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/User:SomeoneElse/Ubuntu_1604_tileserver_load#Updating_your_database_as_people_edit_OpenStreetMap) (and note that that that uses a forked mod_tile repository which fixes a few issues with updates) - that might be a bit easier to follow and also describes how to only apply changes for a particular geographical area.